# Работа с динамической памятью. Обработка числовых данных

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Не понимаю как сделать так чтобы выводился адрес ячейки в которой находится минимальный элемент. Помогите пожалуйста.
Точнее приблизительно понимаю что должно быть что-то подобное на index = &(a[imin][jmin]);, но не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void Min(float** a, int N, int M ,   float& min )
{
    int imin = 1000, jmin = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (i <= j && a[i][j] < min)
            {
                min = a[i][j];
                imin = i;
                jmin = j;
            }
        }
    }
    min = a[imin][jmin];

}
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    puts ("If you follow the picture, our matrix must be square, otherwise it is not clear how to count");
    puts ("In the task, it is not clear how to correctly create conditions in cycles for a matrix of size N*M.");
    puts ("But the program works correctly:)");
    puts ("---I recommend square matrix---");
    int N,M;
    cout << " Enter the number of rows= ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns= ";
    cin >> M;
    cout <<"----------------------------"<<endl;

    float** a = new float* [N];// Один из способов передачи динамического массива в функцию
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = new float[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = (float)(rand()%20001)/200-100;
            cout << setw(3) << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    float min = 1000.00;

    Min(a, N,M, min);
    cout <<" ----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << endl << "Local min element = " << min << "\n";
    puts("In the task it is not clear what is meant by \"results\"");
    puts("So I find a pointer to the minimum element");

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        delete []a[i];
    }
    delete []a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: подробнее опишите проблему и что вы пытались сделать. Из вопроса совершенно не понятно ни что вам нужно, ни в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Мне нужно вывести адрес min

Comment: пишите `std::cout << &min << std::endl;`

Comment: если я просто пишу cout << &min , то у меня постоянно выводится одно и тоже значение

Comment: а почему оно должно быть разным?

Comment: Может просто аргумент ещё добавить `,int & imin,int & jmin)`? Тогда вы получите в main все индексы.

Comment: то есть не смотря на размеры матрицы и местоположение min , все время должно выводиться один и тот же адрес ?

Comment: Если не нужны индексы, то так : `..,float * * minp){... (*minp) = &(a[i][j]); `

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: О, да , получилось , большое спасибо Вам )

Comment: попробуйте передавать ссылку на адрес , так культурнее

Comment: @MVY `min` - переменная, когда вы присваиваете ей другое значение адрес не изменяется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передаём ссылку на указатель:

```
void Min(float** a, int N, int M ,   float * & min )
{
    int imin = 1000, jmin = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (i <= j && a[i][j] < min)
            {
                min = &(a[i][j]);
                imin = i;
                jmin = j;
            }
        }
    }
//    min = a[imin][jmin];

}

...

float * min = 0;

    Min(a, N,M, min);
cout <<" ----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << endl << "Local min element = " << *min << "\n";
    cout << endl << "Local min element address = " << min << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя размер твоей динамической матрицы NXM но память ты выделяешь везде под N элементов!Пересмотри внимательно!